# Hot swaping Erlang port

Tags: erlang, hot-code-replace

I'm starting to learn Erlang which is an amazing language thanks to isolation, fault tolerance, function programming and hot swaping of the code.

I could notice that to fix some performance issue sometimes I can use port to interact with C or other languages.

My wonder is the capacity of hot code replacement using port. Do you have already face this issue in a running system?

May an identification based on hash can help to identity the version of the port to use?

Thanks

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what you are trying to do? without knowing your actual goals it is hard to provide guidance.

Comment: Imagine having a erlang which need C program (for perform op) or python (for deep learning), and these applications communicate through port with the erlang processes. So if I need to update on running systems, how can I do hot swaping with ports?